# why print(2 == 2.) returns True in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

why `print(2 == 2.)` returns `True`

As per my understanding `2` is integer  and `2.0` is float. They both are stored differently in memory.

I think it is returning `True` because they both belong to same class that is `integer class`?

I have gone through similar stack overflow question but concept is still not clear to me. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Because it’s explicitly supported: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory representation doesn't really have anything to do with it (or at least, it doesn't prevent certain integers from comparing equal to equivalent real numbers).

`2 == 2.` is implemented by `int.__eq__(2, 2.)`, which is defined to handle integer/float comparisons by making appropriate type conversions. Since `int` is a "narrower" type than `float`, `2` is first converted to a floating point value. (As an implementation detail, I suspect this is done by `int.__eq__` calling `float.__eq__(2., 2)` and the conversion is done there, rather than the `int` type knowing any particular details about how floating-point values are represented.)

Note that not *every* `int` can be represent exactly as a floating-point value, as `int` uses arbitrary precision but `float` is fixed. For example, on my machine

```
>>> 2000000000000000000000000000000000 == 2000000000000000000000000000000000.
False
```

(I copy-pasted the integer to produce the floating-point literal, so the 0s line up.)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how python implements the equality operator between float and int. I would imagine that in this case the int is cast to float before performing the comparison under the hood.

Comment: It's not implementation-dependent, it's specified by the language. See the linked question.

Comment: It's implementation-dependent in the sense that Python doesn't specify any particular implemantion of floating-point values; it leaves it up to the machine's native type.

Comment: @chepner: [The Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) says “A comparison between numbers of different types behaves as though the exact values of those numbers were being compared.” So the floating-point type is irrelevant; an integer number and a floating-point number will compare equal if and only if they represent the same value, regardless of what values either type can represent. (It is possible that the floating-point

Comment: How is the floating-point type irrelevant to the set of values it can represent?

Comment: The problem is that not every floating-point *literal* produces a unique floating-point *value*. Consider something like `2000000000000000000000000000001. == 2000000000000000000000000000002.`. You could get `True` or `False`, depending on how much precision your underlying floating-point representation has available to store the mantissa.

Comment: @chepner: The floating-point type is irrelevant to the result the `==` operation produces. For numeric operands, `==` evaluates to true if and only if its two operands represent the same value, regardless of what values either type can represent.

Comment: @chepner: Re “The problem is that not every floating-point literal produces a unique floating-point value”: This has nothing to do with how `==` behaves. Conversion of source text to types is a separate step.